# IBM web server error

Tags: ibmhttpserver

Am using ibm http server 6. There am facing some issues . I have mention below the error

**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network**

please advise me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Appears that this is a known issues with Apache (upon which IHS is based).

Check out [Apache error codes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/faq/error.html#error.acceptex)

[image]
[Microsoft error descriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(v=VS.85).aspx?tduid=(b88690c01422cdc77a106fa1540242aa)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-oQudAUhIO9EFdXTiOIQRIw)())

[image]

For  detailed descriptions of the error - mainly on Windows apparently.